# WooCommerce GET Requests wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?page=1 shows random categories on each call?

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Our onlineshop recently has issues getting the correct category orders over to our stock management system via API.

Whenever we test the API Calls in Postman with:

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?page=1
```

we get a completely random category order output like this:

First call:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5179,
        "name": "Redmi Note 2022",
        "slug": "redmi-note-2022",
        "parent": 3054,
```

Second call:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5181,
        "name": "Displayeinheit",
        "slug": "displayeinheit-redmi-note-2022",
        "parent": 5179,
```

Any advice how we can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved:

The problem was caused by the plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/